# identifying trends and classifying using sql

Tags: sql, design-patterns, teradata

i have a table xyz, with three columns rcvr_id,mth_id and tpv. rcvr_id is an id given to a customer, mth_id is a column which stores the month number( mth_id is calculated as (2012-1900) * 12 + 1,2,3.. ( depending on the month). So for example Dec 2011 will have month_id of 1344, Jan 2012 1345 etc. Tpv is a variable which shows the customers transaction amount.

```
Example table

rcvr_id mth_id tpv

1       1344   23
2       1344   27
3       1344   54
1       1345   98
3       1345   102
          .
          .
          .
so on

P.S if a customer does not have a transaction in a given month, his row for that month wont exist.
```

Now, the question. Based on transactions for the months 1327 to 1350, i need to classify a customer as steady or sporadic.

Here is a description.

[image: This pattern is for 1 customer .. i have millions of customers]

The above image is for 1 customer. i have millions of customers.

How do i go about it? I have no clue how to identify trends in sql .. or rather how to do it the best way possible.

**ALSO i am working on teradata.**

*Ok i have found out how to get standard deviation. Now the important question is : How do i set a standard deviation limit on my own? i just cant randomly say "if standard dev is above 40% he is sporadic else steady". I thought of calculating average of standard deviation for all customers and if it is above that then he is sporadic else steady. But i feel there could be a better logic*

Comment: instead of average i am now gonna use standard deviation of standard deviation

Comment: Looking at your edit, you might want to ask a new quesiton on how to use standard deviation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the `STDDEV_POP` function - a higher value indicates a greater variation in values.

```
select 
rcvr_id, STDDEV_POP(tpv)
from yourtable
group by rcvr_id
```

`STDDEV_POP` is the function for [Standard Deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

If this doesn't differentiate enough, you may need to look at regression functions and variance.

Comment: a litte example on how i could use it? or perhaps a link so i could read about it.

Comment: the answer is right, but add a where condition as i want only the last 2 yrs or so.

Comment: Do you know if stddev_pop can be used in an analytic function, e.g. `stddev_pop(tpv) over (partition by rcvr_id)`   Being able to do this would mean can avoid the group by and at the same time be able to filter by signal-to-noise type considerations, e.g. `where tpv between avg_tpv + 3*stdv_tpv and avg_tpv - 3*stdv_tpv` ?